# Running a process in an external cmd window and then exiting it after a time

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to write a batch script to start docker service, but I want that service to stop and restart every hour or so.
But how do I make the exit command override the running docker service?

```
start "s1" cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\dockerd" -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 && timeout 5 & exit"
```

Comment: It seems to me as if your `exit` command is unnecessary, as it should just exit the `cmd` window, _(and that should close anyhow, due to the `/c` option)_.  Also if you want to stop and/or start something acording to a schedule, you should be utilising Windows Task Scheduler, not by starting a constantly running batch file with some built in timing mechnaism. In addition to that, this site doesn't provide a code to request service, please use the search engine if you need code from this site.

Comment: In reference to using task scheduler, I had task scheduler run this script and told it to kill the process after an hour, but it would not kill the running script.   
```:x    
echo This test will run for an hour to see if task scheduler will kill this task  
timeout 5  
goto x  ```
Any idea what needs to be done to schedule a restart of a never ending task via task scheduler?